# Set a bitmap as background and crop it

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, crop

I'm trying to set a bitmap image as background of a FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_list_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_list_header_cnt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game_list_header_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game_list_header_sub_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem with this is that the height of the image I want to set as background is bigger than the height of the two TextView's so the height of `game_list_header` doesn't fit to to the TextView's height but the ImageView height.

I tryied different approaches, such as using the bitmap as a DrawableBitmap with `gravity=clip_vertical|fill_horizontal` but even in that way, the height of the image doesn't fit with the TextView's height, causing the FrameLayout is bigger than I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set image as a background of `game_list_header_cnt`?

If that does not help, you can simply use `ConstraintLayout` and make `imageView` `top_top` of a top `textView` and `bot_bot` of bot `textView`

Comment: Yep, I've already tried your first suggestion and the result wasn't good. But I'll give a chance to the ConstraintLayout. Thanks

Comment: dont forget to use scaleType attribute on imageView

Comment: Yep, the ConstraintLayout did the job. I had to change the ImageView height to wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

Set height of **FrameLayout** to, may be, **40dp**. Since you have set the height of the FrameLayout as **wrap_content**, XML will consider the height of the image also.

Comment: sure that using a fixing height will solve the problem, but I can't use a fixed height because I don't know the TextView height and it will change often

Answer (score 1):

`layout_height` of `TextView` is set to `wrap_content`, so the actual height of `TextView` is determined by the textsize of `TextView`.

you could set `layout_height` of `FrameLayout` a number, such as 80dp, and set `layout_height` of `LinearLayout` as `match_parent`.

Comment: sure that using a fixing height will solve the problem, but I can't use a fixed height because I don't know the TextView height and it will change often

Comment: I see, constraintlayout can suit  you, wait minutes, I will test and post newer answer.

Comment: Thanks, I used a ConstraintLayout, as Max Aves suggested previously,  and it works